# How to continue training serialized AllenNLP model using `allennlp train`?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, transfer-learning, allennlp

Currently training models using AllenNLP 1.2:

```
allennlp train -f --include-package custom-exp /usr/training_config/mock_model_config.jsonnet -s test-mock-out
```

The config is very standard:

```
"dataset_reader" : {

        "reader": "params"

    },
    "data_loader": {
        "batch_size": 3,
        "num_workers": 1,
    },
    "trainer": {
        "trainer_params": "various"
    },


    "vocabulary": {
        "type": "from_files",
        "directory": vocab_folder,
        "oov_token": "[UNK]",
        "padding_token": "[PAD]",
    },

    "model": {
        "various params": ...
    }
```

and serializing them to  the `test-mock-out` directory (also have `model.tar.gz`).

Using the `allennlp train` command, is it possible to continue training? The documentation states `Model.from_archive` should be used, but it's unclear how the config should be adapted to use it.

http://docs.allennlp.org/v1.2.0/api/commands/train/

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "continue training"?

Comment: Hey Arjun, yes sorry for the vagueness. I mean train on the same or similar data (identical vocab, etc.). Will `--recover` parameter work out of the box for this use case?

Comment: Yes, using `-r` or `--recover` with the same serialization directory should work!

Comment: Great thanks, I was able to get something working using `from_archive` parameter under `type` in `model`

Comment: Hi I realize this is old, but I find that my server doesn't have enough space in the /var/tmp folder it tries to extract `my_model.tar.gz` to. Is there any way to tell it to extract the archived model to a custom location?

Comment: By tell 'it', I mean, is there some way we can modify the config jsonnet file to tell AllenNLP to extract the archived model to custom location?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so to continue the training, one solution is to load the model `from_archive`.  Assuming you have the serialization directory, make a `model.tar.gz` archive of the folder. Then, you can make a new config that is identical, except for the `model` key which uses  `from_archive`:

`retrain_config.json:`

```
{
### Existing params ###
 "data_loader": {
        "batch_size": 3,
        "num_workers": 1,
    },
    "trainer": {
        "trainer_params": "various"
    },
### Existing params ###
...
"model": {
       "type": "from_archive",
       "archive_file": "path/to/my_model.tar.gz"
    }

}
```

Then, use your original train command, pointing to this new config:

```
allennlp train -f --include-package custom-exp /usr/training_config/retrain_config.json -s test-mock-out
```

Note that your vocab and output dimensions/label space should remain consistent. Also, it seems like the global training epochs are not preserved.

Alternatively, if you just want to keep training on the exact same training data, and you just have the serialization directory, then you can avoid having to compress the directory, and just keep adding results to the same directory.

```
  allennlp train -f --include-package custom-exp /usr/training_config/mock_model_config.jsonnet -s test-mock-out --recover
```